# Парсинг другого сайта с Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Есть определённый сайт с матчами. Я также сделал RESTful API на Django. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы раз в 20 секунд с Django парсились данные о новых матчах и добавлялись в базу.

Я хотел сделать так: бесконечный цикл и таймаут в отдельном файле parser.py в папке с проектом, но я думаю, что это костыль. Помогите более элегантно решить эту проблему.

Кроме того, в бесконечном цикле нужно использовать timeout'ы, чтобы делать задержку в 30 секунд.

Comment: Ну а что если взять приложение, которое просто будет писать в вашу же базу сайта? Или в отдельную базу? И оттуда уже сайт читает данные, а вся логика парсинга прописана в этом отдельном приложении

Comment: Сделай скрипт, в который будешь стучаться crontab`ом

Comment: @Terraxer В самом проекте или вне его?